# Graphhopper on emulator - No maps in list

Tags: android, android-emulator, maps, graphhopper, mapsforge

After installing graphhopper and maps (/sdcard/graphhopper/maps) into emulator, the dropdown list is empty.
I have followed all the instructions as given inthe github-wiki. is there anything else that needs to be done?

I tried even with the demo apk, but it failed while launching

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/127#issuecomment-38962291) and is fixed only in the very recent versions - we will update download links shortly. So please try to build from master or [one of those apks](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/graphhopper/graphhopper-android/0.3-SNAPSHOT/).

Comment: Thanks Karussell appreciated...One problem which i noticed is with the offline map path. According to git-wiki doc, the maps should be places in /sdcard/graphhopper/maps but the program looks at /storage/sdcard/Download/graphhopper/maps... Once corrected, it worked like a charm

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this is device dependent, I'll leave a note there.